# Python Pandas - sum values of column and merge it to one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I got this structure of the .csv file

```
ID;NAME;PRICE1;PRICE2; some other random columns
1;John;45;20
```

I am using Pandas library for parsing this .csv file like this:

```
col_list = ["ID", "NAME", "PRICE1", "PRICE2"]
df = pd.read_csv(inputCsv, usecols=col_list, sep=";", encoding="utf-8")
```

How can I now sum values of Price1 and Price2 and the result safe to a new column instead of these two to get this result?

```
ID;NAME;PRICEFINAL 
1;John;65
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is multiple `PRICE` columns use:

```
df1 = df.filter(like='PRICE')
df['PRICEFINAL'] = df1.sum(axis=1)
df = df.drop(df1.columns, axis=1)
```

If only 2 columns sum with remove columns in [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html):

```
df['PRICEFINAL'] = df.pop('PRICE1') + df.pop('PRICE2')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's pretty easier than I thought :)